# How to make shortcode which returns HTML?

Tags: shortcode, html, visual-editor, wp-editor, post-editor

I need to make a shortcode button to TinyMCE editor which, in the moment i click it fills up the content part with HTML.

When i click on button i need something like:

```
<div> ... </div>
```

And not:

```
[div] ... [/div]
```

I made my shortcodes work but i need this too.

Any help?

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: @birgire i cannot post here all the code from the function because its too long ... but it is something like `function two_columns_shortcode( $atts) {return 'some html content'}`

Answer (score 1):

You can check this out - [wpgallery plugin](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/fb019893f983ff47d7d92e93e08ffbe979ebaafb/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpgallery/plugin.js), this is how they do it for the [gallery] shortcode, basically parsing the shortcodes on the client-side, and replacing them back and forth as you click "Visual" or "Text".

Unless you are building a plugin, I would advise you to refrain from using shortcodes - use plain HTML, you'll have an easier time working with the DOM, and the article contents will be more or less portable across themes.